# How to 'join/associate' 2 dataframes so EACH row of the left dataframe is 'attached' to EVERY row of the right dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have gone through the pandas docs on  'Merge, join, concatenate' [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/merging.html) but getting nowhere.

```
leftdf = pd.DataFrame({'m': ['K1']})

rightdf = pd.DataFrame({'k': ['K0', 'K1', 'K1', 'K2'],
                'lv': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                's': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

frames = [leftdf, rightdf]
pd.concat(frames, sort=False, ignore_index=True)
```

result is...

```
    m   k   lv  s
0   K1  NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN K0  1.0 a
2   NaN K1  2.0 b
3   NaN K1  3.0 c
4   NaN K2  4.0 d
```

What I am after is a result of...

```
    m   k   lv  s
0   K1  K0  1.0 a
1   K1  K1  2.0 b
2   K1  K1  3.0 c
3   K1  K2  4.0 d
```

So notice that another requirement is that there are to be no NaNs. The leftdf will always have fewer rows than the right so when a single leftdf row is 'attached' to every row of the rightdf the element values are to forward filled.

Also the leftdf cannot be a Series as it will have more than 1 column. I am using a 1 column df for simplicity here.

There is no common index values nor column names.

The reason is that I am extracting relevant pieces of JSON and needing to construct a flat table. All of these "relevant pieces" do not necessarily exist in every JSON object. Sometimes they do and sometimes they don't. I have to save certain pieces when they are there and somehow 'join' them to other pieces as the 'other' pieces are come across.

I wonder if I have to convert these to numpy arrays? Can this be done using ndarrays (rhetorical). I'll try to explore pandas as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` with `ffill`

```
rightdf.join(leftdf).ffill()
    k  lv  s   m
0  K0   1  a  K1
1  K1   2  b  K1
2  K1   3  c  K1
3  K2   4  d  K1
```

Or `concat` but with `axis = 1`

```
pd.concat(frames, axis = 1).ffill()
    m   k  lv  s
0  K1  K0   1  a
1  K1  K1   2  b
2  K1  K1   3  c
3  K1  K2   4  d
```

Comment: Thank you very very much @YO and Ben_W. In the "Merge, join, and concatenate" pandas documentation ffill is only mentioned once but as a parameter in merge_ordered() AND there are NaNs all over that page so I wonder by what process of extrapolation one could arrive at using it as a method but more to the point even of its existence. I see in the ffill documentation a terse comment "Object with missing values filled". Sigh!